# Open-source solution for serving my own podcast

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, web-server, podcast

I want to serve my own podcast. I do not need the podcast to have a web interface. I am using Ubuntu. So I need solutions to two problems:

1. Serving the files on http. I currently use Python’s simple http server but I guess that won’t scale well?
2. Generating and updating the rss feed automatically from the files in a folder.

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to question 1: [Apache httpd](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-apache#0) (link is getting started tutorial).  It is free, open source, and used by millions, if not billions.  See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693741/whats-difference-between-a-simple-webserver-and-apache-server).

With regards to question 2:  I have no experience with RSS.  Hopefully someone else can chime in here while you get Apache up and going!